# Android show ActionBar without navigation items

Tags: android-actionbar, android-navigation

I would like to display the `ActionBar` alone without any navigation buttons(Home, back,etc) which are present at the bottom of the screen.
If I use '`@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`', then even the `ActionBar` is not present.

Is there a way to display ONLY the ACTIONBAR without the navigation bar at the bottom?

Comment: You want to place the ActionBar on the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hiding the Navigation Bar, which is there only since API 14, see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

[image]